# Query a VIEW - Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'm writing T-SQL scripts in SSMS. I am connected with read/write access to *AdventureWorks2012*. When attempting to query either VIEWs created by myself or the VIEWs included with the database I get the following error (the object name changes depending on which VIEW I query):

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'HumanResources.vMYVIEW'

```
SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[vEmployee]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to declare that I want to **USE AdventureWorks2012**, 
the code is now:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[vEmployee]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connected to the appropriate database the view is defined in. Also, as the error says prefix the `database` name so the database engine recognizes the object.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM databasename.[HumanResources].[vEmployee]
```